# How -thin_with_grid works?

Tags: lidr

I'm curious about how `-thin_with_grid` is actually performing thinning tasks within `lidR`.

Which point is selected? One point within the grid is randomly sampled? Is it possible to select for example the lowest?

I know there is a full list of filter parameters with `lidR::readLAS(filter = "-help")` but I think this part of documentation is relatively poor (e.g. clear info about input parameters or how to combine different filters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is poor because the documentation of `LAStools` is poor. `lidR` relies on `rlas` which relies on `LASlib` to read LAS/LAZ files. `LASlib` is the library developed by and for `LAStools`. If you look at the documentation of `LAStools` you won't find anything more. Thereby `rlas` and consequently `lidR` cannot document more the filters.

The only way to know in depth what happens is to read the source code which is not trivial in the case of `-thin_with_grid`. And the answer is: **it keeps the first point it encounters in the file for a given pixel**.

And no, there is no way to keep the lowest or the highest. This is not part of the open source `LASlib` library. The close source part of `LAStools` have such tools but in `lidR` you must use `decimate_points()` to achieve such task.

I plan in the future to add something like `-thin_highest_with_grid`, `-thin_lowest_with_grid` but it is not for a close future.

Comment: Yes but decimate_points doesn't have a lowest algorithm. In my case, I have a very dense classified point clouds and I want to keep one (the lowest) ground by pixel before rasterizing

Comment: Ask a new question, I will show you how to create a custom function `lowest()` for `decimate_points()`

Comment: FYI I added `lowest()` in `lidR` 3.1.2

Comment: the question is here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389100/how-to-create-a-lowest-function-for-decimate-points-using-lidr